# How can I change the language of the LibreOffice's interface to Spanish?

Tags: libreoffice

I had recently installed LibreOffice 5 by executing these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

The interface is by default in English. Can I change it to Latin American Spanish?

Comment: no up vote ? =)

Comment: Yes of course!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change user interface language in libreoffice:

1. Make sure the language pack is installed.

   For this,open "Language & region " in system settings.

   Click on <kbd>comple install</kbd> under "install missing languages" ,**if** the required language is not available.

   Note: No need to change any other settings in that tab.

2.Go to `libreoffice` **tools**-->> **options..** -->> **language settings** -->> **language**.

3.Now change **User interface, Locale setting , Default currency** , and **default document language** to desired language.

This will change the language **only** for LibreOffice, leaving other applications in English.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1):

tools -> options ->Language Settings -> language

you can change the language to the language you want and you installed

Answer (score 1):

In Debian:

> sudo apt-get install libreoffice-l10n-es

Answer (score 0):

This video clearly shows how to do this on Mac OS
https://youtu.be/uT5F_OxrMy8